# Android MusicPlayer uses Stagefright or opencore

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, stagefright, opencore

I read that if `media.stagefright.enable-player` is set `true` then the device uses `Stagefright`.
In my device's `build.prop` i see

```
media.stagefright.enable-player = false
```

When i tired below

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(String.format("http://127.0.0.1:%d/", socketPort));
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

I hosted a server socket to which the mediaplayer connects

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         socketPort = serverSocket.getLocalPort();

        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = socket.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        byte [] temp = new byte [1024];     
        int bsize = -1;
        while(bsize <= 0) {
            try {
                bsize = is.read(temp);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        final String readData = new String(temp);
        Log.e("readDta",readData);
```

The log i get is

```
11-22 15:06:56.656: E/readDta(8737): GET / HTTP/1.111-22 15:06:56.656: E/readDta(8737): Host: 127.0.0.111-22 15:06:56.656: E/readDta(8737): User-Agent: stagefright/1.1 (Linux;Android 2.3.6)
```

Now my doubt is,, how it shows me `User-Agent: stagefright/1.1` though it's set `media.stagefright.enable-player = false` in `build.prop` ?

If it's not a way to determine which is used, how can i detect whether `opencore or stagefright ?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your logs, I feel that the version of `Android` is `Froyo 2.2.3` which is the probably one of the last versions before `Stagefright` became a default. The choice of player is dependent on multiple conditions like whether it is a `file` source or `http` source or `rtsp` source.

In `Froyo 2.2.3`, there are 2 keys for enabling `Stagefright` player and a build flag. To enable the use of `Stagefright` player for normal playback, you need to build the framework code with `BUILD_WITH_FULL_STAGEFRIGHT` as observed from here: http://androidxref.com/2.2.3/xref/frameworks/base/media/libmediaplayerservice/MediaPlayerService.cpp#670

`getDefaultPlayer` is called for multiple conditions and in cases where the aforementioned macro is defined, it would try to check the value of the system property `"media.stagefright.enable-player"` (Ref: http://androidxref.com/2.2.3/xref/frameworks/base/media/libmediaplayerservice/MediaPlayerService.cpp#750)

In your case for `http` source, there is a different system property which is checked viz., `"media.stagefright.enable-http"`. In your case, I feel that this is enabled/set to true and hence, `Stagefright` player is being employed. Please set this to `false` to enable `PV_Player` only.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is an ancient prop from GB, what Android are you using? I did not see this in the usage in the code even in GB... What I can imagine is that "media.stagefright.enable-player false/true" means that stagefright player is/is not used what does not mean that libstagefrigt.so (framework which uses Open MAX) is or is not used. When I was working with GB libstagefright, so Open MAX was in use always (only some codecs in GB were not ported to OMX).

Comment: So, you mean GB have OpenMax for codecs, if so, can i access codecs by calling openmax il apis from jni?

Comment: Any guidance on how to use openmax with stagefright from our ndk application?

Comment: @nmxprime..Yes `GingerBread` has `OMX` for some of the codecs. However, you can't access the component in a standalone fashion. This support was introduced in `JellyBean`. Can you confirm which version of android are you working on?